# Trigger function only when var has been certain value for a certain amount of time in jQuery

Tags: javascript

There is a var `i`, change value from `0` to `9` constantly and randomly; trigger function `A` only when `i==1` for 200 milliseconds. Wondering if there are any functions to work this out?

Comment: Since you are able to set it periodically, why can't you do this from within your existing code?

Comment: Hey Adam, if use setTimeout or delay, function A is going to be triggered after 200 miliseconds. If i changes during the time, A is still going to be triggered. That's something I don't want.

Comment: Blender, I won't be able able to set the time period. it's random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use `setTimeout`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)</sup>* to monitor the value of the variable. I would set the interval at 200ms and set a flag when the variable is the target value. If the variable is still the target value on the next interval, execute your function.

```
var i = 0;

function A() {
}

$(function() {
    var targetFlag = false,
        targetVal = 1,
        triggerA = function() {
            if (i == targetVal) {
                if (targetFlag) {
                    A();
                } else {
                    targetFlag = true;
                }
            } else {
                targetFlag = false;
            }

            setTimeout(triggerA, 200);
        };

    triggerA();
});
```

Comment: Using a `setTimeout()` within a function that holds the executing test would probably be a more effective method in this case than a `setInterval()`, which can fire erratically over time.

Comment: This summarizes my point and shows an example of the technique: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval#Dangerous_usage

Comment: And I don't know if you've noticed it, but you have `$(`, although a library is not mentioned or indicated.

Comment: Sure. I updated my code example.

Comment: @Jared The tag was edited out, but the body of the function remains the same.

Comment: My reading of the question was that `A()` should be called only if `i` was 1 continuously for 200ms. Doesn't this answer check the value of `i` at two specific moments? What if `i` was changed to some other value or values and then changed back in between each timeout?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but something along this line should work for what you're trying to do:

```
//called when i == 1
function setTrigger( triggerCallback, testCondition, time ) {
    var _triggerIfTrue = function () {
        trigger( triggerCallback, testCondition, time );
        if(testCondition()) {
            triggerCallback();
        }
    };
    return setTimeout( _triggerIfTrue, time );
}

//called when i != 1
function removeTrigger( triggerId ) {
    clearTimeout(triggerId);
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
function callBack() {
    //do something 
}

function testCondition() {
    //if i == 1, return true
    //else return false
}

var i, triggerId;
function updateValue(newI) {
    i = newI;

    if( i == 1 )
        triggerId = setTrigger(callBack, testCondition, 200);
    else 
        removeTrigger(triggerId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following calls `A()` only if `i` has a value of 1 continuously for 200ms.

Update your code so that it doesn't ever change the `i` variable directly. Instead, create a `setI()` function. Within that function, if the new value is not 1 you clear any previous timeOut. If the value is 1 and there isn't already a timeout you set a new one (I'm assuming here that setting it to 1 several times in a row doesn't reset the timeout). Something roughly like this:

```
var i,
    timerID;
function setI(val){
   i = val;

   if (val != 1 && timerID != null) {
      clearTimeout(timerID);
      timerID = null;
   }

   if (val === 1 && timerID === null) {
      timerID = setTimeout(function() {
        timerID = null;
        A();
      }, 200);
   }
}
```